# How to use datastore id instead of key_name?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

How to define that?

What should be used instead of

- `get_by_key_name`
- `SELECT __key__`
- `key().name()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `get_by__id()`
- no change; it's still a key whether it has an ID or a name
- `key().id()`